# Warning message: corrupt data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, compiler-warnings, tibble

I am trying to create a data frame but the below code gives a warning message. Anyone know what the problem is?

```
library(tibble); library(magrittr); library(tidymodels); library(dplyr)

c(28L, 13L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 3L) -> points
c(100L, 91L, 8L, 5L, 13L, 12L) -> hours

tibble(points, hours) -> monthly

linear_reg() %>%
  set_engine("lm") %>%
  fit(points ~ hours, data = monthly) ->
  lm_fit

expand.grid(hours = seq(5, 30, 5)) %>%
  mutate(predicted = predict(lm_fit, .))

#  hours                                    predicted
# 1     5      \033[38;5;246m# A tibble: 6 x 1\033[39m
# 2    10                                        .pred
# 3    15   \033[3m\033[38;5;246m<dbl>\033[39m\033[23m
# 4    20                \033[38;5;250m1\033[39m 0.885
# 5    25                \033[38;5;250m2\033[39m 1.98 
# 6    30                \033[38;5;250m3\033[39m 3.08
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `predict()` method called on `lm_fit` returns a tibble/data frame. I think you just want the predictions column of that data frame, `.pred`. You can get that through standard subsetting:

```
expand.grid(hours = seq(5, 30, 5)) %>%
    mutate(predicted = predict(lm_fit, .)$.pred)

  hours predicted
1     5  0.885311
2    10  1.983003
3    15  3.080695
4    20  4.178386
5    25  5.276078
6    30  6.373770
```